# How to make a draggable image appear on link hover?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, draggable

How to make a draggable image appear on link hover? Just like in [this website](https://kulbachny.com/)

I will post some more images:
[image]

[image]
[image]

I am using React, so if it works with a library, i will be happy to take recommendations

Answer (score 0):

You must present what you have done till now, so we can help. consider this for your next questions. Btw you can use something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    const img = e.currentTarget.querySelector("img");
    const {
      x,
      y,
      width,
      height
    } = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    img.style.display = "block";
    img.style.transform = `translate(${e.pageX - img.clientWidth / 2 - x}px,${
      e.pageY - img.clientHeight / 2 - y
    }px)`;

    if (
      e.pageX > width + x ||
      e.pageY > height + y ||
      e.pageX < x ||
      e.pageY < y
    ) {
      img.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    const img = e.currentTarget.querySelector("img");
    img.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: tomato;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  cursor: none;
}

.title {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  display: none;
  max-width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<a class="item" href="#">
  <h3 class="title">Title</h3>
  <img src="https://kulbachny.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/jg-cosmos.jpg" />
</a>
```